# How can I download a torrent to the SD card using BitTorrent?

Tags: sd-card, downloading, bittorrent

How can I download a torrent to the SD card using BitTorrent?

I tried to go to Settings -> Default Download Folder, but I can't see to be allowed to browse to the SD storage location (see error below when I click on the back arrow):

[image]

[image]

I use [BitTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving to SD card  isn't officially supported - this is not documented in the support (at least, I couldn't find it) but it's mentioned in reply to user review (user name - Sujeet)

[image]